# TopologyTestDriver testing with JSON to Avro Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a test class where I want to test two topologies.
For this scenario, I am creating two TopologyTestDriver instances with those topologies.

One of my topologies is creating a stream from avro and producing avro, which is working fine.
Other one should read json and produce an avro. This one is failing with this exception

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing JSON message` 
this happens when i call
topic.pipeInput("key", messageObject);

my inputTopic is created like this

`jsonTopic = driver.createInputTopic( "jsonTopic", stringSerde.serializer(), messageSerde.serializer());`

And this is how I create my messageSerde:

```
final Serde<Message> messageSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(
                        new SchemaRegistrySerializer<>(Message.class, kafkaConfig),
                        new SchemaRegistryDeserializer<>(Message.class, kafkaConfig));
Map<String, String> config = Map.of(
                AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, MOCK_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

messageSerde.configure(config, false);
```

Also, my KafkaConfig:

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAV3f.png)

I tried everything and I cannot make it work with the json topology :D
Thanks a lot!

Tried to initialiaze different serdes, even used objectMapper and JsonSerializer class but still not working.